# How to set header in html table

Tags: html, css

I am working with HTML tables and need to create a header in a certain way.

My desired result is shown in the image below. But I am having trouble getting this result using HTML & CSS.

[image: my desired result]

So far, I have the below code, but the result is not exactly right.

How can I modify my code to get the desired result?

```css
table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: solid black 1px;
}

td {
  border: solid black 1px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th rowspan="2">head</th>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could remove the border from `table` and add it specifically to the `th`. You can remove the `rowspan` attribute and use a `class` instead. I added a second `th` which serves only as a spacer.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
.hz-header {
  border: solid black 1px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="hz-header">head</th>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by removing the `rowspan` attribute and using an empty filler `th` in the next row instead. Then just set a border on your visible `th` (`th.label`) and remove the border on the `table`.

Full example:

```css
table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 5px;
}


th.label,
td {
  border: solid black 1px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th class="label">head</th>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```